# Telerik grid and large cells

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid

I have problem with ASP.NET MVC Telerik Grid.
In my grid I have comment column and some columns contains too large text.
This effects to row height. I need that all rows have same height.
How I can reduce the text? I tried to add HTML abbr, but it doesn’t work.

Best regards Paul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [custom formatting](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/customformatting), you can check the length of your text, and if the text length is greater than a certain number, you can limit the length by using substring. For example, if your comment column is called "Comment", you could do something like this:

```
Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
.Name("MyGrid")
.CellAction(cell => 
  {
    if (cell.Column.Title != null)
    {
      if (cell.Column.Title.Equals("Comment"))
      {
        if (cell.DataItem.Comment.Length > 25)
        {
          cell.Text = cell.DataItem.Comment.Substring(0, 25) + "...";
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

**Update**
You asked about showing the complete comment. I don't know of a simple way built into the telerik control, but you can do it using css. I am using css code from [kollermedia.at](http://www.kollermedia.at/archive/2008/03/24/easy-css-tooltip/), but there are lots of examples of css tooltips if you want a different style.

In your css, put something like this:

```
/* tooltip */
a:hover {background:#ffffff; text-decoration:none;} /*BG color is a must for IE6*/
a.tooltip span {display:none; padding:2px 3px; margin-left:8px; width:130px;}
a.tooltip:hover span{display:inline; position:absolute; background:#ffffff; border:1px solid #cccccc; color:#6c6c6c;}
```

Then change the line in your view to this:

```
cell.Text = "<a class=\"tooltip\" href=\"#\">" + cell.DataItem.Comment.Substring(0, 25) + "<span>" + cell.DataItem.Name + "</span></a>";
```

When you hover over the shortened text, the complete text is displayed in a tooltip.

Comment: Thank you so match that will by useful. 
More question how I can show truncated comment (may be pop-up)?

Comment: @Paul, I updated the answer to answer the question you asked in the comments.